# How to use Rules to flag a node on behalf of ALL users who had previously flagged it with a different flag?

Tags: rules, flags

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

- I have a content type of Question.
- Questions have a field that identifies their status as "asked" or "answered".
- Questions marked "asked" can be flagged (using Flag Module) as "follow" by users.
- When an admin changes the status field of a Question from "asked" to "answered" I would like to flag the Question with an additional flag called "archive" for all the users who "follow" the question.

**This is how I set up the rule:**

**1. Events:** 
After updating existing content

**2. Conditions:** 
Entity has field (Parameter: Entity: [node], Field: field_question_status)
*AND*
Data Comparison (Parameter: Data to compare: [node:field-question-status], Data value: Answered

**3. Actions:**
Fetch users who have flagged a content (Parameter: Flag: Follow, Content: [node]
Provides variables: Users who flagged (users)
*LOOP*
(Parameter: List: [users]
List item: Current list item (list_item))
*ACTION-IN-LOOP*
Flag a Content (Parameter: Flag: Archive, Content: [node], User on whose behalf to flag: [users:0], Skip permission check: true)

**Here's my problem:**

The rule seems to be working for only one user at a time. So if 3 users have "followed" a Question and it is switched to "answered" status only one of the users will have the Question flagged as "archive". I found I can specify an individual user in the *ACTION-IN-LOOP* (action nested in the loop) by changing the value of "User on whose behalf to flag: **[users:0]**". If I switch the value to users:1 or users:2 then the rule works for those individual users but not all. The only other option I can think of is to try [users] without any additional chained value, but this gives the error "The data type of the configured argument does not match the parameter's flagging_user requirement." How do I get a rule to flag the node (with "archive) on behalf of ALL users who had previously followed it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to flag on behalf of the user that the loop is operating with each iteration. Either that or add a numerical variable that you increment each loop and fetch that index from the list of users for the behalf of which to flag